# Laptop sleeps while using android studio or visual studio

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, dell-vostro

I have dell Vostro 14 3468 
Below are the Details attached

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hewq.png]

Whenever the CPU utilization increase the laptop sleeps. I have tried to change the sleep settings through Registry Options by going into power options and from command prompt also.
I don't know what the problem is because When I use my Laptop with the charger plugged but the battery removed it doesn't sleep and I can work on my projects.
How can I stop my laptop from going into sleep or hibernation mode?

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with your battery.

Comment: @DAvidPostill is it the driver issue or battery circuit/IC issue?

Comment: I've no idea :/

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > System and select Power & sleep on the left. Click on Additional power settings (on the right).

Now you are in Control Panel: click on Change when the computer sleeps (or Change plan settings), then click on Change advanced power settings.

Click on Sleep > Sleep after, then click on Settings and select Never. Do the same in Hibernate after, then click OK.